# Expected Number of items

Tags: probability, statistics

Need help with this practice exam question.

An item is present in a list of n items with probability p; if it is present, it is position in the list is uniformly distributed. A computer program searches through the list sequentially. Find the expected number of items searched through before the program terminates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:

- First assume that the item is present; in that case what is the expected number of items searched through?
- Now assume that the item is not present; what is the expected number of items searched through?
- The actual expected number is a certain weighted mean of the two numbers just calculated; what is it?

Comment: if the item is not present, then the expected number of items searched through is n. How do you calculate it, if the item is present.

Comment: @ab: Do you know the definition of the expected value of a random variable?

Comment: yes, at least I am pretty sure I do

Comment: @ab: That’s all you need here. You have a random variable $X$ whose value is the number of items searched through; its possible values are the integers $1,\ldots,n$, and each of those is equally likely and therefore has probability ... what? With that information and the definition, $\Bbb E(X)$ is straightforward to calculate.

Comment: each probability would be 1/n, there it would be (1/n)(1) + (1/n)(2)....(1/n)(n). Is this the expected value, if item is present?

Comment: @ab: Yes, it is. And it simplifies to a pretty simple fraction involving $n$.

Comment: So the fraction would be (n+1)/2? But what is the weighted mean of the two numbers. How do i determine the weights

Comment: @ab: Yes, $\frac{n+1}2$ is correct. The last part is just another application of the definition of expected value: with probability $p$ the expected value is $\frac{n+1}2$, and with probability $\underline{\text{something}}$ it’s $\underline{\text{something else}}$; can you finish it off now?

Comment: i understand what u mean, just struggling figuring out the weights

Comment: would it with probability 1-p

Comment: @ab: Right: with probability $1-p$ the item is not in the list, and the expected value is $n$. So with probability $p$ the exp. val. is $\frac{n+1}2$, and with probability $1-p$ it’s $n$, and the overall exp. val. is therefore ... ?

Comment: (p)((n+1)/2) +(1-p)(n)

Comment: @ab: Looks good; all that remains is to simplify it.

Comment: thank you, this actually makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @ab: You’re welcome; glad it helped.